# dynamic dropdown not responding to change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown named field2 based on the value of another dropdown named field1 with laravel 5. The problem is that when I change field 1, nothing happens with field2. What is wrong?

This is my form:

```
<form action="/automations" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="automationForm">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <!-- Task Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
        <label for="task-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Field 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {!! 

                Form::select(   
                    'field1', 
                    (['0' => 'Select a Field'] + $fields), 
                    (isset($field->id) ? $field->id : null),  
                    ['class' => 'form-control']
                ) 


            !!}
        </div>
        </div>



            <!-- Task Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="task-name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Field 2</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! 

                    Form::select(   
                        'field2', 
                        (['0' => 'Select a Field'] + $fields), 
                        (isset($field->id) ? $field->id : null),  
                        ['class' => 'form-control']
                    ) 
                !!}
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Automation
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And this is my js code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#field1').change(function(){
            $.get("{{ url('api/dropdown')}}", 
                { option: $(this).val() }, 
                function(data) {
                    $('#field2').empty(); 
                    $.each(data, function(key, element) {
                    $('#field2').append("<option value='" + key +"'>" + element + "</option>");
                    });


                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the routes.php file:

```
Route::get('api/dropdown', function(){

  $id = Input::get('option');
  if($id == 0) {

    $field2 = array(
                1 => 'Enable',
                2 => 'Pause',
            );

  } else {

    $field2 = array(
                1 => 'Not Enable',
                2 => 'Pause',
            );


  }

    return $field2;
});
```

Comment: You need to echo your array instead of returning it. Try echo json_encode($field2).

Comment: thanks, but didn't work

Comment: Did you check if the callback for the ajax-request is ever called?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? If you are not, then could you please use console.log to see what data your controller is returning